# author's index with imakeidx in LaTeX

Tags: indexing, imakeidx

I am not an expert at all with LaTeX; I used it for the very first time some month ago to compose a conference proceedings volume modifying an already available script.

I am trying to refine the final aspect of the this year edition of the proceedings using  personalized authors and affiliations indexes.

I make use of the `imakeidx` package with LaTeX and I would like to know if it is possible to:
1) substitute the default comma separating the index entry from the first page number in the index with a colon; as an example I would like to have

> Einstein Albert: 1, 2, 3

instead of the predefined

> Einstein Albert, 1, 2, 3

2) control the indentation of lines following the first in the index; with predefined settings I obtain something like

```
Einstein Albert, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
       6, 7, 8
```

Any hint?

Answer (score 13):

For getting the colon you need to define a new MakeIndex style; it's really simple: just prepare the following `31083.ist` file in the same folder as your main document, with the single line

```
delim_0 ": "
```

because `delim_0` is the container of the tokens inserted between an index entry and the first page number (if any). Then you have to instruct `imakeidx` to use the newly defined style.

For controlling the indentation of the following lines, you have to modify the definition of `\@idxitem`; something like

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@idxitem}{\par\hangindent=20pt }
\makeatother
```

will use 20pt instead of the default 40pt.

Complete example.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=people,title=Index of People,options=-s 31083.ist -r]

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@idxitem}{\par\hangindent=20pt }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Relativity}

Einstein\index[people]{Einstein, Albert}
Zorro\index[people]{Zorro}

\newpage
Einstein\index[people]{Einstein, Albert}
Zorro\index[people]{Zorro}

\newpage
Einstein\index[people]{Einstein, Albert}
Zorro\index[people]{Zorro}

\newpage
Einstein\index[people]{Einstein, Albert}
Zorro\index[people]{Zorro}

\newpage
Einstein\index[people]{Einstein, Albert}
Zorro\index[people]{Zorro}

\newpage
Einstein\index[people]{Einstein, Albert}
Zorro\index[people]{Zorro}

\newpage
Einstein\index[people]{Einstein, Albert}
Zorro\index[people]{Zorro}

\newpage
Einstein\index[people]{Einstein, Albert}
Zorro\index[people]{Zorro}

\printindex[people]

\end{document}
```

I have used also the option `-r` to disable implicit range formation, otherwise the example would have shown "1–8" so not going to the second line. You'll probably want to remove it.

[image]

Comment: Dear egreg, thank you very much for your answer and clear example; I just used your hints in my script and it works great. Regards. Francesco

Comment: @user31083 Please, when you have time, have a look at the site's FAQ, particularly http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation